# \\NAME\share gets permission denied whereas \\IP\share doesn't

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7, authentication

Scenario:

- Windows 7 Pro client
- Windows Server 2k3 Domain

  1. Client tries to access \\Machine\share and gets permission denied
  2. Client tries to access \\IP\share and is allowed access.
  3. Client CAN access \\SomeOtherMachine\share, this only fails with a specific Machine
  4. net use reports no other connections to Machine (or anywhere else for that matter)
  5. This behavior persists between reboots.

Causes? What further info is required to debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that Windows is using a cached set of credentials when using \Machine?  Is there another share accessed on that machine using a different username, that doesn't have access to \share?

Comment: Edited the question with more info I thought about after reading your answer. But, how do I know if Windows is using a cached set of credentials? I've already tried rebooting.

Comment: Check in Run > `control userpasswords2` > Advanced > Manage Passwords.

Comment: Cached set of credentials was it. Deleted them and voilà.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified DNS is correct? With AD problems this is more often than not the problem. Check that the client and server machines both have valid DNS entries(and check the DHCP server).